# Compiler Error for Nullable Bool

Tags: c#

```
 bool? ispurchased = null;
    var pospurcahsed= ispurchased ? "1":"2";
```

Its generating exception .

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

What I am doing wrong here?
thanks for your support and consideration.

Comment: That's not the error message I get, mine says `Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)1`

Comment: @George Duckett sorry for typo error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not allows because it is unclear what null means in the context of a conditional.

`Nullable Booleans` can be cast to a `bool` explicitly in order to be used in a conditional, but if the object has a value if null, `InvalidOperationException` will be thrown.

It is therefore important to check the HasValue property before casting to `bool`.

Use like

```
   var pospurcahsed=  (ispurchased.HasValue && ispurchased.Value) ?......
```

Nullable Booleans are similar to the Boolean variable type used in SQL. To ensure that the results produced by the & and | operators are consistent with SQL's three-valued Boolean type, the following predefined operators are provided:

```
bool? operator &(bool? x, bool? y)

bool? operator |(bool? x, bool? y)
```

[image]

or you can use `martin` suggestion `GetValueOrDefault`[*Thanks to martin to pointing it out* ]

The GetValueOrDefault method returns a value even if the `HasValue` property is false (unlike the Value property, which throws an exception).

Comment: `ispurchased.HasValue && ispurchased.Value` can be reworded as `ispurchased == true`, which IMO is more readable.

Comment: Or as `ispurchased.GetValueOrDefault()`

Comment: @hvd won't `isPurchased==true` throw if it is null?

Comment: @Tejas - No. It is fine to compare a `bool` and `bool?`

Comment: @Tejas its like false && null=false

Answer (score 2):

The issue you have is that the conditional operator `? :` expects a `bool`, not a `bool?`. You could just cast it and be done, but you'd get an `InvalidOperationException` if the value contained a `null`, so you should probably check for that first.

Given the name of your variable, I've gone ahead and assumed you'd want to treat a `null` as you would `false`, so in the code below I check to ensure it has a value, and if it does then it'll use it in the condition. In the event it doesn't have a value (i.e. it's `null` then the cast will never happen and you won't get the error (the expression would evaluate to false).

```
bool? ispurchased = null;
var pospurcahsed = (ispurchased.HasValue && (bool)ispurchased) ? "1":"2";
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use **.value**

```
bool? ispurchased = null;

if (ispurchased.HasValue)
{
    var pospurcahsed = ispurchased.Value ? "1" : "2";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `Nullable<bool>` or `bool?` in condition directly, instead use it like:

```
var pospurcahsed= (ispurchased.HasValue && ispurchased.Value) ? "1":"2";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
 bool? chk = false; 

 //or

 bool? chk2 = false;

 var test = (chk != null && (bool)chk) ? "1": "2";

 //or

 var test2 = (chk2.HasValue && (bool)chk2) ? "1" : "2";
```

I would suggest don't use `var` keyword for known types.

Instead of this use  Like this:

```
String test = (chk != null && (bool)chk) ? "1" : "2";
```