# Conditional expression with nullable bool produces compiler error

Tags: c#

See the following property:

```
public bool LeftChecked {get;set;}
public bool RightChecked {get;set;}
public string LeftRight
{
    get
    {
        return !LeftChecked && !RightChecked ? null :
            LeftChecked ? "L" : "R";
    }
}
```

My goal with this property was to do the following:

- Return null if both LeftChecked and RightChecked are equal to false
- Return "L" if LeftChecked is equal to true
- Else return "R"

This works as I expect it, but now I would like to do something similar, except with a bool? instead of a string. See the following property.

```
public bool PassChecked {get;set;}
public bool FailChecked {get;set;}
public bool? PassFail
{
    get
    {
        return !PassChecked && !FailChecked ? null :
            PassChecked ? true : false;
    }
}
```

However, this gives me the following error:

`Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between '<null>' and 'bool'`

So I rewrote it using if-else instead...

```
public bool? PassFail
{
    get
    {
        if (!PassChecked && !FailChecked) return null;
        else return PassChecked ? true : false;
    }
}
```

I have no problems with using the if-else method, however I'm really curious why my original property would not work, even though it is almost the same as the string property which worked.

I have read a few SO questions such as this [Compiler Error for Nullable Bool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16456016/compiler-error-for-nullable-bool) however I have not come across any with similar circumstances.

Comment: return PassChecked ? true : FailChecked ? false : default(bool?);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work :

```
return !PassChecked && !FailChecked ? null :
            PassChecked ? (bool?)true : (bool?)false;
```

Comment: Wow, I'm surprised that the compiler does not implicitly cast true and false to bool? in this situation whereas it would in others. It also didn't underline those values, it actually underlined `null :`... Anyway, that did indeed work, thank you!

Comment: @rshepp Check this post for explanation - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858080/nullable-types-and-the-ternary-operator-why-is-10-null-forbidden

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand using the expression `PassChecked ? true : false`. The `PassChecked` property is already of type `bool`. What's the point of sending it through the ternary operator just to return new `bool` values identical to the original value?

This (practically the same as the suggestion by slugster in the comments) should work just as well:

```
return PassChecked ? true : FailChecked ? false : (bool?)null;
```

Alternatively, if you prefer the basic structure of the original expression:

```
return (!PassChecked && !FailChecked) ? (bool?)null : PassChecked;
```

I prefer `(bool?)null` to `default(bool?)`, but it's strictly a matter of taste. They are equivalent and work equally well.

Comment: I simply copied the string version of the property and changed the values, I was more concerned with the error than simplifying the expression.

Answer (score 0):

The code in the original question now "just works" in C# 9 using the [target typed conditional expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/target-typed-conditional-expression) feature.

---

Historically, the conditional operator's type was determined by looking at the type of the latter two operands, and if a conversion exists from one operand to the other operand, then we use the "other" operand as the operator's type. ([simplifying a bit](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/3c8559f186d4c5df5d1299b0eaa4e139ae130ab6/spec/expressions.md#conditional-operator).)

In this case, we have one operand that is `null`, and another operand of type `bool`. Only the `bool` operand has a type in this case, and `null` can't be converted to `bool`, so the language pre-C# 9 wasn't able to determine a type for the conditional expression.

Now that we have target typed conditional expressions, the compiler can observe that this expression is used in a position where a value of type `bool?` is required. Based on this it simply tries converting each operand to `bool?`. The expression `null` converts to `bool?` just fine, as does the type `bool`, so it just does the right thing in this scenario and gives the conditional operator the type `bool?`.